# Constructor parameter - IList<CustomType>

Tags: c#

I am using a third party API which has a class. The constructor of this class accepts `IList<CustomType>`. Here is the constructor per its documentation

```
public LogicalOrFilter(
IList<ElementFilter> filters
)
```

I have tried passing in a `list<ElementFilter>` when I initialize this object. However it does not work, it does not throw any runtime error. Being a third party API, I do not know its internal workings. This class has another constructor that just accepts a single `ElementFilter`. When I use that, the class does what I want. So I am sure the rest of my code is okay. Can anyone explain which standard data structure could I pass in to this constructor.

Comment: Can you add the code you've tried to your question? Could be some small thing we can pick out.

Comment: Does the 3rd party provide any sort of API support?  Sounds like a question for them directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List<ElementFilter>` implements `IList<ElementFilter>` so you are fine calling it with that.

If it doesn't work, talk to the original author of the third party item. It could either be a fault with their code or a fault with your expectation of what the code should be doing.

Answer (score 1):

It should allow a generic List, but you can always download Reflector to look inside the API to see what the constructor is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Should work as you've described it.  This code works:

```
public class Blah
{
    private IList<string> _strings;

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this._strings.Count; }
    }

    public Blah(IList<string> strings)
    {
        _strings = strings;
    }
}
```

Then somewhere else:

```
List<string> someStrings = new List<string> { "a", "B", "c" };
var blah = new Blah(someStrings);
Console.WriteLine(blah.Count);
```

Prints out `3`